# Find the available RAM using GO API

Tags: rest, go, kubernetes, minikube

I am using the Minikube environment and I have defined the max memory using

```
$] minikube config set memory 2048
```

Now I want to get this memory value using the Kubernetes API call in GO.
I have tried the following,

```
import (
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
)

availableMem := kubernetes.Interface.StorageV1beta1().RESTClient().Get().Name("config")
```

But the output is not in readable manner.

Comment: Minikube is essentially a single Node kubernetes. Resources available on a Node should be part of the v1.Node object. The status member should contain information about allocatable RAM.

Comment: I will be running the same in K8S cluster as-well. In that case also v1.Node works fine ?

Comment: Yes, you can issue requests to the apiserver to get node information, either all the nodes, or a specific node by name. In those objects will be information about node capacities. And a specific pod can get its node ip and name via the downward api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will fetch the available memory of the first cluster

```
nodeList, err := f.KubeClient.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})

if err == nil {
   if len(nodeList.Items) > 0 {
        node := &nodeList.Items[0]
        memQuantity := node.Status.Allocatable[v1.ResourceMemory]
        totalMemAvail = int(memQuantity.Value() >> 20)
    } else {
        t.Fatal("Unable to read node list")
        return
    }
} else {
    t.Fatalf("Error while reading node list data: %v", err)
}
```